# Unable to get the library path right with minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am trying to use a standard Ruby file layout. I have a few Spec files and trying to use Minitest to run those tests. I understand that I should not use 'lib' when requiring files as that could be appended generally when giving Ruby library path using '-I'. When running spec files, I get some minitest constant unitialized errors.

1. Can someone please explain why do I get this error?
2. What should I do to resolve this error?
3. Does the rakefile look good?

   ```
   /Users/rag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/minitest-5.8.1/lib/minitest/parallel.rb:19:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Minitest::Parallel::Executor::Queue (NameError)
       from /Users/rag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/minitest-5.8.1/lib/minitest.rb:23:in `new'
       from /Users/rag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/minitest-5.8.1/lib/minitest.rb:23:in `<module:Minitest>'
       from /Users/rag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/minitest-5.8.1/lib/minitest.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/rag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
       from /Users/rag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
       from /Users/rag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/minitest-5.8.1/lib/minitest/autorun.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/rag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
       from /Users/rag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
       from tests/test_jthread.rb:1:in `<main>'
   ```

spec file:

```
cat tests/test_jthread.rb 
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'thread.rb'

describe JThread do
```

directory structure:

```
lib/thread.rb
bin/
tests/test_jthread.rb 
Gemfile
jta.gemspec*
```

gem list from bundle:

```
$ bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:

      * ansi (1.5.0)
      * builder (3.2.2)
      * bundler (1.10.6)
      * minitest (5.8.1)
      * minitest-reporters (1.1.4)
      * ruby-progressbar (1.7.5)
```

rakefile

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |task|
  task.libs << %w(tests lib)
  task.pattern = 'tests/test_*.rb'
end

desc "Run tests"
task :default => :test
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class `JThread`, it should be located in `lib/j_thread.rb`, also fix `require 'thread.rb'` to `require 'j_thread'` (no `.rb` suffix needed).

If your rake task doesn't work, try to check it by running your tests old-fashioned way:

```
ruby -Ilib:test tests/test_*.rb
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 1.where is the naming convention that requires JThread class to be in a file j_thread.rb. I cannot figure out from `http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require`. 2. even though file name was the problem, the error thrown did not give a clue regarding the problem. 3. is this `task.pattern = 'tests/**/test_*.rb'` the correct pattern in rake testtask to run all test files under any directory level within tests?